# how to generate vertical scale on both sides of the plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Usually on a plot the vertical scale is on the left, and the horizontal scale is on the bottom. How to make the vertical scale appear on both left and right, and similarly the horizontal scale on both top and bottom? This just makes my life easier when after exporting the file I can still see the scale even if I zoom-in the right or top region of the plot.

Comment: You mean `FrameTicks`?

Comment: Try with Frame -> True

Comment: To close voters: If `Frame` were an option listed for `Plot` or `ListPlot` in the docs, I would say the answer is easily found in the docs.  But since it's **not**, I would say it's not easily found. (Might be a duplicate, though, if one could be found.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have yet to vote to close, but allow me to disagree. Just above the options table in the Details section of both `Plot` and `ListPlot` is the statement "... has the same options as Graphics, with the following additions and changes".

Comment: @rcollyer You're free to disagree. :) In my mind, it is a borderline case, and our comments mean that people will at least think about it before deciding.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think every plotting/charting function has that link, and if it doesn't, it should (or the equivalent for `GeoGraphics). So, I think there's a bit of space with the border. :D

Comment: @rcollyer You remind me of a time in 1993 when I told myself to remember that lesson about looking at both `Plot` and `Graphics`. I can fix the date because I remember the house we lived in. I wish the close reason read "can be found in the documentation (and easily understood)". Sometimes I vote that way. You may convince me yet in the present case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, All}}, ImagePadding -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: It works for `Plot`, but I find that if I use `ListPlot`, even if I include the `FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, All}}` it is not showing the right and upper frame. why is that?

Comment: It works; e.g. `ListPlot[Table[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi, 0.01}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, All}}, ImagePadding -> All]`.